# How can I access the outer class instance of a non-this instance of nested class in Java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm familiar with the `ClassName.this` syntax to access the outer class instance of the current instance in the lexical scope of a nested inner class. What is the syntax to access the outer class instance of *another* instance?

For example, consider the following types:

```
public class A {
    public int fieldA;

    private class B {
        public int fieldB;

        public void foo(A.B other) {
            /* Hypothetical code goes here... */
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `B#foo`, I know I can use the syntax `A.this.fieldA` to access the current instance's outer instance's field `fieldA`. How do I access the same information for `other` (e.g., something like `other.B.this.fieldA`)?

I know I can add an instance method (e.g., `getOuterInstance`) to `B` that simply returns `A.this`, which would let me call `other.getOuterInstance()` in the above example.  However, I'm hoping there's some built-in syntax I'm just not aware of.

Comment: There is not, and you already know solution.

Comment: @andreas thank you for finding the existing question. I had tried -- and failed! -- to do so!